# Can OpenGL ES render into CPU memory?

Tags: opengl-es

Is it possible to render all of the **OpenGL ES** things into a normal *allocated* buffer instead of the framebuffer:

```
/* render into this buffer */
GLubyte* buffer =
(GLubyte*) calloc(width * height * 4, sizeof(GLubyte));
```

I want to be able to convert those rendered images into textures for other uses.

I'm using **OpenGL ES 1.3** with the standard C API.

Comment: By the way, are you sure there is a 1.3 version of OpenGL ES? I thought there is only 1.0, 1.1 and 2.0. But I might be wrong, as I don't have any ES experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you won't get around a call to [glReadPixels](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml), which copies the content of the framebuffer into system memory. But when you want to copy it into a texture you can do this directly using [glCopyTex(Sub)Image2D](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCopyTexImage2D.xml) or by using [FBOs](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html) and rendering directly into the texture without the need for a copy (but I'm not sure if FBOs are supported in ES). But of course, you cannot render directly into system memory (for textures it works using FBOs, as they are stored in GPU memory).